# Android (Jelly Bean Only) - MapActivity Overlay Causes Out of Memory Error

Tags: android, memory, overlay, android-4.2-jelly-bean

---

UPDATE (2.8.2013): Thank you to Geobits for the lesson in Bitmaps! I did not think of PNG being a compressed format (one of those DOH moments) :D

In the end though there is still a issue between older versions of Android and Jelly Bean...here is a screen shot of the heap on my ICS phone and one on the JellyBean Emulator...ICS = <6MB, JB = >22MB for the exact same app, exact same image!

(ICS using <6MB heap):
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7GW5mJ5fr3XSTFYWU54VjdUTEk/edit?usp=sharing

(JB same app - the one below - using >22MB):
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7GW5mJ5fr3XUGlCdHNMUGJJVFE/edit?usp=sharing

So the question remains...what are the older versions doing to prevent OOM conditions that JB isn't? And how do I cover this in Jelly Bean without lowering the resolution a TON (I have to go down to very pixelated overlays to avoid OOM in JB)?

---

I'm having a Jelly Bean specific issue with a MapActivity and a large Bitmap overlay. When looking at the heap on the first run with Jelly Bean is is taking up over 22MB, compared to ICS which takes up ~6MB. On each run after it grows and depending upon the size of your Bitmap it will give you an OOM error or just have a super large heap.

APP DESCRIPTION (what this sample app does)

This below is not my original app...I've made a fully functional app with code below to duplicate the issue and keep the code simple; this is a application with a parent activity (Start.java) and child activity (MainActivity.java). Start.java is just a screen with a button that will load MainActivity.java (I spared no expense on time ;).

MainActivity.java will load the map and has one large overlay. My overlay is a clip of part of NY from GoogleMaps that I added a filter on in GIMP so you could tell it's different. This overlay is then "pinned" to the map by the "topLeft" GeoPoint and "bottomRight" GeoPoint so it will zoom when you zoom on the map.

The Bitmap is ~7MB large...so it appears that with JellyBean it's loading it 3x (Heap is ~22MB). Watching the heap I see it start at 8MB, then quickly move to 16MB & 22MB. It is also located in the "res/drawable-nodpi" folder.

I saw this issue with previous version & the "fix" was to put the bitmap in the "drawable-nodpi" which is why it lives there, but for JellyBean this multiple loading is back (old issue link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906037/android-mapactivity-overlay-bitmap-not-relasing-memory-when-finish-executes)

THINGS I'VE TRIED
1) Tried putting the Bitmap in all of the drawable folders (-ldpi, -mdpi, -hdpi, -xhdpi)
2) I've tried making the overlay smaller...it does stay away from OOM crash BUT still loads 3x...and since my other more complex app has other smaller images this isn't a solution
3) I tried creating a "res/drawable" folder and putting the Bitmap in this, it crashes on the first load of MainActivity.java - seems to load more than 3x)
4) Added a bitmap.recycle() in the onDestroy() method - this does keep this sample app from OOM error but as mentioned, it's the taking 3x MB up that I need to fix most.

Project Name - TestMapOverlayJB
Full Code ZIP Archive (minus my MAP Key - you will need to add your own)
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7GW5mJ5fr3XY3h1MmFuREpoaDA/edit?usp=sharing

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testmapoverlayjb"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Start"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MyBaseImageOverlay" />
    </application>
 </manifest>
```

Start.java:

```
package com.example.testmapoverlayjb;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Start  extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start);

    Button buttonMainMenuSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNY);
    buttonMainMenuSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         try {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(Start.this, MainActivity.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
         }
         catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Activity Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
         }
    }});
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.testmapoverlayjb;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
    Bitmap bitmapMapOverlay;
    MyBaseImageOverlay baseLargeOverlay;
    MapView mapView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);


        GeoPoint topLeft = new GeoPoint((int)40723714, (int)-74029412);
        GeoPoint bottomRight = new GeoPoint((int)40704522, (int)-73976011);
        bitmapMapOverlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ny_base1);
        baseLargeOverlay = new MyBaseImageOverlay(topLeft, bottomRight, bitmapMapOverlay);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(baseLargeOverlay);
        MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16);
        mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)40715029,(int)-74001975));
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mapView.setStreetView(false);
        mapView.postInvalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        bitmapMapOverlay.recycle();
        baseLargeOverlay = null;
        mapView = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

MyBaseImageOverlay.java:

```
package com.example.testmapoverlayjb;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class MyBaseImageOverlay extends Overlay {
    private Bitmap baseBitmap;
    GeoPoint topLeft;
    GeoPoint bottomRight;

    public MyBaseImageOverlay(GeoPoint topL, GeoPoint bottomR, Bitmap bmp) {
        baseBitmap = bmp;
        topLeft = topL;
        bottomRight = bottomR;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    if(shadow) {
           return;
        }
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        // convert bitmap's bounding box into pixels 
        Point top_left = new Point(); 
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(topLeft, top_left); 
        Point bottom_right = new Point(); 
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(bottomRight, bottom_right); 
        // Prepare two rectangles (pixels) 
        Rect src = new Rect( 0,0,baseBitmap.getWidth() - 1, baseBitmap.getHeight() - 1 ); 
        Rect dst = new Rect( top_left.x, top_left.y, bottom_right.x,bottom_right.y ); 

        // draw bitmap 
        canvas.drawBitmap(baseBitmap, src, dst, null); 
    }
}
```

start.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonNY"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="NY" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="YOUR_MAP_KEY_HERE"
/>
```

Overlay Bitmap:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7GW5mJ5fr3XZFdWYnVBUW45bWM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, your bitmap isn't ~7MB large, that how big your PNG is. It's compressed(unless you're working with a 16bpp colorspace). Your image is 2800x1324, so assuming a normal ARGB_8888 format, it should take up ~15MB uncompressed. 7 for the PNG to load, plus 15 for the uncompressed bitmap... comes to 22. So, during the time it's decompressing the image into memory, it's going to be using all of that.

You mentioned several things you tried which got rid of the OOM error(smaller bitmaps, recycling), but didn't fix the "3x" issue. You can try using `Bitmap.Config.RGB_565` to load the images. That should save some memory at the expense of quality(should only use about ~15MB total), but other than that you can't do a whole lot apart from what you've tried.

Comment: You rock! Thanks for the info...but the next question is why doesn't this have any issue with 4.0.3 or 2.2 (those are the two actual phones I have) and they work great...

Comment: I think it's mainly due to the use of 3D acceleration everywhere. If you can't find a way around it at all, you might try enabling `largeHeap` in the manifest. Not recommended by Google in general, but better than nothing if your app absolutely requires it.

Comment: Again, thank you! I am learning I have much to learn about graphics! Thanks for the lesson!